# How to do URL rewriting in ASP.net by using Htaccess?

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I tried to rewrite URL by using below code in .htaccess file but its not working.

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.aspx [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.aspx -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.aspx [L]
```

Comment: Not working as in, it crashes your system? It generates a dinosaur? The server does not start? There is no redirect? What happens? What webpage are you opening? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There is no redirect in my website. i want to hide the extension .aspx. please suggest the proper way , i am beginner in asp.net

Comment: Is `mod_rewrite` loaded?

Comment: yes. can you please give the code for hiding .aspx extension 

domainwhitepages.com/home.aspx to 

domainwhitepages.com/home

Comment: Are you sure the server is apache? If so, check the server's config file (`httpd.conf` or `apache.conf`) and search for line: `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` Uncomment it, restart the server